# In physics, where do we come across terms like $({\bf A} \times \nabla) \times {\bf B}$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vectors, vector-fields

Recently I have come across the term $({\bf A} \times \nabla) \times {\bf B}$ in the vector identities page of wikipedia. I would like to know if this type of term is encountered anywhere in physics and mechanics? Can we attribute a physical meaning to such terms?

Comment: Check Navier-Stoles equations or derivation of the Poynting theorem.

Comment: Do you mean specifically a reversed curl crossed with a vector, or any combination of say, a curl cross another vector or the dot product of a vector with a curl?

Comment: @RogerVadim I cannot remember any instant where one come across terms like reversed curl.

Comment: @R.Romero I specifically mean a reversed curl crossed with a vector

Comment: $\nabla \times \vec{A}$ is the curl of $\vec{A}$. I was referring to $\vec{A} \times \nabla$ as "reverse curl". I should have put in the quotes.

Comment: @R.Romero I understand your previous comment. Now can you help me with the info that if we encounter this type of term anywhere in physics other than vector identities?

Comment: At first I was thnking the Poynting Theorem would do, however, that involves a vector crossed with a regular curl instead of a reversed curl crossed with a vector. I think I have a proof that the combined operations are non-associative which is unfortunate. The reverse curl cross product seems to simplify calculations regarding the gradient of hte electromagnetic field energy density which in turn has some applications for Maxwell's E&M Tensor.

Comment: There might be something in quantum mechanics. The angular momentum operator is $\vec{r} \times (-i\hbar \nabla)$. But then I'm not sure if there's any vector to multiply it by that would be physically significant.

Comment: This question is currently the subject of [a post on meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13987/168783)

Answer (score 6):

The force on a magnetic dipole $\vec{m}$ in an external magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is given by $$\vec{F} = (\vec{m} \times \vec{\nabla}) \times \vec{B}.$$ Note the similarity with the electric case $$\vec{F} = (\vec{p} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{E}.$$

Comment: Would you mind sharing where/how you found this formula?

Comment: @TexasTachyon: See Jackson: "Classical Electrodynamics", 3rd ed, Eq. (5.68)